# Style efficiency in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Someone asked me which style from below is a faster? I got confused.

Can anyone please help me here?

```
span li a
{


}

a
{

}
```

Comment: [Article about the topic](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/). But keep in mind, the two codes above are not the same, the second one styles `all links`, the first just the links somewhere in a `li` element, which has to be somewhere in a `span` element.

Comment: Not to mention that the first one is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Since descendant selector are the most expensive selector.

```
Span Li a{
}
```

tag is more expensive than

```
a{
}
```

for info click [here](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/#article-header-id-3)